# What's the life-time of a function parameter (citation needed)?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, c++14

Is the life-time of a function parameter equal of an unnamed temporary passed as an 'rvalue' reference (which is equal of the expression called the function)? My 'gcc' compiler shows that it is. But I want to see an actual standard document that states it too (possible the newest 'C++11' or 'C++14').

Comment: Can you clarify the question ? What's the point of the comma operator ?

Comment: What's the life-time of an function parameter? And if possible I need a quote from the ISO standard (C++11 or C++14). The comma operator was added just for a testing purpose - as I wasn't sure if it's a part from expression.

Comment: The example is broken.

Comment: I don't think (str&&)arg would create a copy of arg. Therefore, it would never need to call str's destructor.

Comment: Note that there's an [open bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60372) about GCC not implementing the standard correctly wrt function parameter lifetime. I cannot tell for certain whether it's a legitimate bug, but it looks like it might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`5.2.2 [expr.call]/4`, seems to be the same in C++11 and C++14:

> When a function is called, each parameter (8.3.5) shall be initialized (8.5, 12.8, 12.1) with its corresponding
>   argument. [ Note: Such initializations are indeterminately sequenced with respect to each other (1.9) —
>   end note ] If the function is a non-static member function, the this parameter of the function (9.3.2) shall
>   be initialized with a pointer to the object of the call, converted as if by an explicit type conversion (5.4).
>   [ Note: There is no access or ambiguity checking on this conversion; the access checking and disambiguation
>   are done as part of the (possibly implicit) class member access operator. See 10.2, 11.2, and 5.2.5. —
>   end note ] When a function is called, the parameters that have object type shall have completely-defined
>   object type. [ Note: this still allows a parameter to be a pointer or reference to an incomplete class type.
>   However, it prevents a passed-by-value parameter to have an incomplete class type. —end note ] During
>   the initialization of a parameter, an implementation may avoid the construction of extra temporaries by
>   combining the conversions on the associated argument and/or the construction of temporaries with the
>   initialization of the parameter (see 12.2). **The lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it
>   is defined returns.** The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the
>   calling function. [ Example: the access of the constructor, conversion functions or destructor is checked at
>   the point of call in the calling function. If a constructor or destructor for a function parameter throws an
>   exception, the search for a handler starts in the scope of the calling function; in particular, if the function
>   called has a function-try-block (Clause 15) with a handler that could handle the exception, this handler is
>   not considered. —end example ] The value of a function call is the value returned by the called function
>   except in a virtual function call if the return type of the final overrider is different from the return type of
>   the statically chosen function, the value returned from the final overrider is converted to the return type of
>   the statically chosen function.

Is this what you are asking for?

Answer (score 7):

Although the standard does definitely claim that the lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns, as answered by Anton Savin, this is not what implementations do, [and the standard will likely be changed to allow what implementations do](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1880):

> WG decided to make it unspecified whether parameter objects are destroyed immediately following the call or at the end of the full-expression to which the call belongs.

This means the lifetime of a function parameter would become unspecified. It might end as soon as the function returns, or it might end later.