# When exactly are function arguments being destructed?

Tags: c++, arguments, c++17, destructor, string-view

I have a question because it is not clear to me when function arguments get destroyed. Therefore, is the concatenation of the following doSomething function error-prone or not?

I’m asking because "it is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that std::string_view does not outlive the pointed-to character array". Can that be guaranteed in that specific case or not?

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

std::string doSomething(const std::string_view& str_view)
{
    // do something and create a new std::string instance based on the std::string_view instance

    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::string input_str{"Hello world!"};

    std::string output_str{ doSomething(doSomething(doSomething(input_str))) };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well, you return `std::string`, it doesn't depend on the `std::string_view` anyway.

Comment: The pointed-to character array in this case is `input_str.data()`, which lives until `main` returns, which is definitely longer than any of the `str_view` arguments last.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195825/function-parameters-are-not-destroyed-at-that-functions-exit

Comment: @NathanOliver That question seems to address function parameters and not function arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anonymous temporary passed to the (`const` reference) parameter `const std::string_view& str_view` survives the function call.

Since there are nested functions, the anonymous temporaries are not destroyed until, conceptually, the closing semicolon of

```
std::string output_str{ doSomething(doSomething(doSomething(input_str))) };
```

Comment: Did I understand you correctly, all the std::string's used as function arguments won't only exist as temporary objects at the beginning of the function call (to construct the std::string_view's)? Which means, that they will at least exist until the function body was executed completely?

Comment: @D3V0N5H1R3: Exactly. No `std::string`s are destroyed until you get to `;`. And they are destroyed in the reverse order of construction.

Comment: As an aside, is there any benefit to putting const& on a string_view? My impression was "no".