# Prvalue semantics object lifetime

Tags: c++, copy-elision, return-value-optimization, c++-faq, prvalue

I'm confused about the lifecycle of objects involved in [prvalue semantics](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). For example:

```cpp
struct A {
  int *num;
  A(): num{new int(1)} {}
  A(A &&other) { num = std::move(other.num); std::cout << "moved"; } 
  ~A() { *num = 2; }
};
int* f(A a) { return a.num; }
A returnA() { return A{}; }
int returnInt() { return *f(returnA()); } // 1
```

In my understanding, prvalue semantics would place the object constructed in `returnA` directly as the initialization of argument of f, and there is no temporary object involved. The object would be destroyed at the end of `f`, so we are dereferencing a deleted pointer in `returnInt`. However, when I run the code it seems that when the pointer is dereferenced the destructor for `A` hasn't been called (`returnInt` returns 1; if the `A`'s destructor were called before dereferencing, it would return 2), as if there is some temporary object still in scope. Why?

**Update:** It seems semantically there is a temporary object created by `returnA` in `returnInt` return statement. This is in contrast to if we assign the function call result of `returnA` to a variable - in which case semantically there is no temporary object. Notice in my example it's actually chaining two prvalue semantics. Since prvalue semantics is a new **semantics** that may violate as-if-copy/move rule, is there any theoretical basis that would allow me to reason about such scenarios?

Comment: The object returned by `returnA()` is destroyed at the end of the full expression - at the semicolon, after the `f` call and the dereference.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik When you say "The object returned by `returnA()`", you imply there is a temporary object created. However, shouldn't prvalue semantics prevent this from happening?

Comment: @JaMiT I updated the question to clarify on expected and actual output.

Comment: With copy elission `A returnA()` you can think of `A` being constructed just before the call and used within the call (even though you write it as a local variable). So that's why there is no move or copy.

Comment: For `returnInt` A lives just long enough to make the call but and then is deleted. But you also return a pointer to the address of A's member variable... and you end up with a dangling pointer (a pointer pointing to memory that is no longer yours). Using that pointer later will result in undefined behavior (your program is no longer correct)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Dangling pointer is exactly what I want to observe. Since I set `*num` to 2 before deleting, I expect to see 2 when I dereference the dangling pointer shortly after (although it's UB). But it consistently returns 1.

Comment: Well, an object of type `A` is clearly created. And it is not assigned to any variable or otherwise given a name. What is it if not a temporary object? You yourself cite a passage saying that, when a copy is elided, the single object is destroyed at a latter time of the two objects it replaces. Without copy elision, `returnA()` call would have produced a temporary destroyed at the semicolon. With elision, it does too.

Comment: @JaMiT updated.

Comment: [Here's your code](https://godbolt.org/z/MsT48dreT) with a bit more tracing. In particular, it prints when `operator*` is evaluated. It shows that `A`'s destructor in fact runs after the dereference. Perhaps this will prove illuminating.

Comment: The first question looks rather similar to [Function parameters are not destroyed at that function's exit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27195825), although this is the sort of detail that I could see varying due to defect reports (I don't know if it has). If the reasoning still holds, it would be a duplicate **if there was only one question in this question**.

Comment: @JaMiT The first question is about the semantics of chaining prvalue semantics - i.e. whether chaining prvalue semantics elides temporary objects not only storage-wise but also semantically - and not about _given_ an temporary object what's its lifetime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming C++17 or later for this answer.

---

> In my understanding, prvalue semantics would place the object constructed in returnA directly as the initialization of argument of f, and there is no temporary object involved.

Yes, formally the *result object* of the function call prvalue from `returnA()` and the `A{}` prvalue in the return statement is the function parameter object of `f`. It is directly initialized by `{}` from the initializer of the prvalue in the `return` statement. No temporary object exists and no copy or move is made.

(Note however, that there are exceptions for types that are sufficiently trivial. For them it is implementation-defined whether temporary objects are created. This doesn't apply to your example because it has a non-trivial destructor.)

> The object would be destroyed at the end of f

No, it is implementation-defined whether function parameter objects are destroyed when the function returns or at the end of the full-expression containing the function call. In particular the Itanium ABI and MSVC ABI behave differently in this regard.

So the behavior you observe is valid, as is the one that you expect.

Comment: When you say"function parameter object", you take for granted that semantically there is a temporary object created by `returnA` in `returnInt` return statement. This is in contrast to if we assign the function call result of `returnA` to a variable - in which case semantically there is no temporary object. Notice in my example it's actually chaining two prvalue semantics. Since prvalue semantics is a new **semantics** that may violate as-if-copy/move rule, I want the theoretical basis that would allow me to reason about such scenarios.

Comment: @Elucidase "_you take for granted that semantically there is a temporary object created by returnA_": No, there is no object created by the return statement and there is no temporary object. The function parameter object is the `A` object named `a` in `f` and exists regardless of how `f` is called, although that affects its initialization. It is not a temporary object.

Comment: @Elucidase "_This is in contrast to if we assign the function call result of returnA to a variable - in which case semantically there is no temporary object._:" No, it is 100% exactly the same as initializing a variable with a call to `returnA`. There is no difference between the two cases (in any version of the standard).

Comment: "_Since prvalue semantics is a new semantics that may violate as-if-copy/move rule, I want the theoretical basis that would allow me to reason about such scenarios._": A prvalue initializes its result object. If prvalues are initialized by prvalues of the same type (ignoring cv-qualifiers), then the result object of the inner prvalue is the result object of the outer prvalue. This chain either ends on a non-termporary object such as a variable or on a temporary object materialized by prvalue-to-xvalue conversion. I don't know what "_as-if-copy/move rule_" means.

Comment: If you meant the old non-mandatory copy elision rules, then those are _not_ "as-if" rules. The "as-if" rule always applies to any C++ construct. The copy elision rules permitted the compiler to do optimizations by dropping copy/move constructor calls _even if_ that does not result in the same behavior. Except for where optional copy elision still applies, the new rules get rid of this compiler choice. There is only one remaining valid behavior (which is not calling the copy/move constructor).

Comment: Okay, I seem to have misunderstood what you meant by "function parameter object". But then if "function parameter object" is `a` in `f`, then it has automatic storage duration with the enclosing code block being `f`. Shouldn't it be deallocated at the end of `f`, and why would it be implementation-dependent?

Comment: @Elucidase The lifetime of function parameter objects is specifically handled in https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#6.sentence-10. The creation/destruction also happens in the context of the caller, not of the callee. The rule is like this, because different ABIs implement it differently. Either the caller is responsible for calling the destructor, or the callee is. The standard is written to accommodate both ABI choices, see [defect report 1880](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1880).